# How to detect end of text when writing with keyboard?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode, ipad

I want to detect that text has end on text field when user press delete button to delete the text in the textfield.So when user reach to end of deleting the text then i want to detect it.

I have use following to achieve the task but i am unable to do it.Problem is event after textfield become empty then it does not detect.When i again type after textfield become empty then it detects but that time size is 1 not zero.Please suggest me some idea?

```
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string
{

    if (textField == self.txt_Search)
    {
        NSLog(@"out if");
        if (![string isEqualToString:textField.text] )
        {
            if([self.txt_Search.text length]==0)
            {
                NSLog(@"finished writing");
            }
        }
    }
    return YES;

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check the range to do the trick:

```
-(BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField
shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range
replacementString:(NSString *)string
{
    NSRange backspaceEndRange = NSMakeRange(0, 1);

    if (NSEqualRanges(range, backspaceEndRange)){
            NSLog(@"finished writing");
    }
    return YES;
}
```